# ON breakfast or IN breakfast?

Tags: grammar

1. I miss having beans ON breakfast.
2. I miss having beans IN breakfast.

Which preposition is accurate here?

Comment: `Which preposition is accurate here?` None.You can eat beans **on** a piece of toast or **on** some bread  or **in a bowl**, *in* a saucepan etc.

Comment: Think of another preposition.

Comment: As a part of breakfast, they would be  _with_ breakfast. If they're the main thing you're having, you'd have them _as_ breakfast.

Comment: @kaipmdh I wouldn't - I would have them _for_ breakfast. https://www.insider.com/mediterranean-diet-best-breakfast-food-2019-1

Comment: I can see only *for* or *at* here.

Answer (score 2):

Both of “on” and “in” don’t work as prepositions to describe an addition to your breakfast as you have used them here.

The reason is that **breakfast** here is an entire thing - it is *all* the foods you are eating for that meal. You can’t talk about putting an additional item of food “on” or “in” your breakfast because then it would **be** your breakfast.

I can say I put a tablet “in” my dog’s breakfast because I am hiding something that isn’t really part of her breakfast inside it, so she eats it at the same time.

You can put a *cloche* “on” your breakfast or a *garnish* “on” your breakfast, since they aren’t thought of as part of your breakfast, just things sitting “on” it. You can even say “I like *ketchup* on my breakfast” because we can think of the sauce sitting “on” it as an extra, added after its preparation but not quite being incorporated into the breakfast itself.

To refer to additional items adding to your breakfast, or foods constituting the entirety of your breakfast, you need to use other prepositions like “with” or “for”.